# Kohana3 method invocation from CRON - despite proper routes, always redirected to user/login

Tags: cron, kohana-3, kohana-auth

I have such a problem with running methods in Kohana3 from CRON.

The situation is as follows

1) I have set up (proper ?) CRON jobs in cPanel:

```
php /home/myuser/public_html/index.php --uri=mycontroller/mymethod
```

2) I have set up (proper ?) routes in bootstrap.php:

```
Route::set('myroute', 'mycontroller/mymethod')
->defaults(array(
'controller' => 'mycontroller',
'action' => 'mymethod'
));
```

3) Globally, my app uses AUTH but mycontroller is written in such a way, I can manually access the methods from my webbrowser without the need to log in.

My problem is that proper methods are not invoked from CRON. Instead, I receive cron reports to my email, stating that the invocation was redirected to user/login...

```
Status: 302 Found
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Set-Cookie: session=2a41c5efa2a25efb0c698136abb174f5; path=/
location: http://myserver/~myuser/user/login
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

To be honest, I am out of ideas - what might be the cause and what is the fix? Could anyone help me with that ? Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Peter

Answer (score 0):

I decided to change the approach.

1. I created cron.php file in Kohana root folder
2. The file contains cURL invocations of the controllers/methods I need
3. cron invokes just the cron.php file rather than the controllers/methods directly

All is working fine now.